# Unable to install the "zoo" package (R version 2.15.1)

Tags: r, zoo

I'm currently using R version 2.15.1, and I'm trying to install the "zoo" package, but I get the following error:  "package ‘zoo’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)". Documentation says it depends on R>=2.10.0, are there any add-on packages it depends on that I need to install? I'm using the function "install.packages" to try to install this package, any thoughts thanks.

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.0    lattice_0.20-6   nlme_3.1-104     MASS_7.3-19     
[5] rms_3.5-0        Hmisc_3.9-3      survival_2.36-14

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] cluster_1.14.2     colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2      
[5] grid_2.15.1        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3        plyr_1.7.1        
[9] proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1     scales_0.2.0      
[13] stringr_0.6        tcltk_2.15.1       tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: post your `sessionInfo()`. What repository are you connected to? Works fine for me on osx mountain lion with R 2.15.1. You can also download the zipped source from the CRAN page and install from source.

Comment: Try a different mirror or download it from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html and install it locally.

Comment: Yes. Do post sessionInfo(). I've been having a bunch of problems with installation of packages including with 'zoo'. This is after updating to R2.15.1 running under MacOS Leopard. I have not had similar issues with prior upgrades. (Have already done `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)` which seemed to have little effect. Sometimes problems are being resolved by simply restarting and reloading the problem packages, as fortunately happened with 'zoo'. Other times they are requiring that I install from source and restart.

Comment: `options("repos")` and `?available.packages` are handy

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this problem before when it seems a specific mirror is temporarily having problems with some package. It can be problematic if that mirror is the default.

`chooseCRANmirror()` is helpful in these cases to choose a new default mirror. After choosing a different mirror, the package was found and installed successfully in my case.

Answer (score 2):

chooseCRANmirror() worked in RStudio for me. Changed mirror to UC Berkeley 66. Installed straight up right after that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but with different package in R-Studio. The tip with `chooseCRANmirror()` didn't work for R-Studio (I've tried different mirrors), so I've started bare R console instead.

In the R console the command `install.packages("xts")` worked well (though R asked me to choose a mirror from a list first).

Comment: In RStudio you can go to the `RStudio` menu entry -> `Preferences` (Command-comma on MacOS) -> `General` and find there a button for changing your CRAN mirror.